# Notifications in Microservices Architecture

Tags: nestjs, microservices

I am working on microservices architecture using nest-js and NATS Streaming Server, I want real time notifications on client side. I have two services which generates notifications.

- Restaurant Service ( when restaurant gets approved/rejected )
- Vote Service ( when user Upvote/Downvote on a review )

**Need suggestions on a valid approach.**

**Approach I found**

- Generate events such as UpvoteEvent, DownvoteEvent etc, and listen to those events in a dedicated notification service which stores the notification and uses socket.io and client initially connects to notification service and after event is published socket server will generate a new socket event which user will listen on client app.

I am using `@nestjs-plugins/nestjs-nats-streaming-transport` plugin in my nest application.